# Nginx 405 Not Allowed when using Docker Container

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, containers, devops

Nginx React application is working properly in our local machine. but when we deployed it into Production Linux host environment it's not working. First landing page is browsing as expected but when we hit submit button it gives **405 Not Allowed** error. whenever we request submit form this issue comes. we are using nginx and react application.
Nginx port's are 80:80, 443:443 and React Application port's are 9000:3000.

This is Default.conf :

```
 server {
        listen 80;       
        server_name www.example.com ;
        index index.html;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT,";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range";
        add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Length,Content-Range";
        add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000;
       
        

        location / {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
          error_log /etc/nginx/app_error.log;
          return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;                          
      }
    }  
     server { # This new server will watch for traffic on 443        
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.example.com;    
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/example.com.key;  
                               
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1; 
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=500; 

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT,";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range";
        add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Length,Content-Range";
        add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000;        
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        
        location / {                      
           proxy_pass http://serverlocalIP:9000;           
           error_log /etc/nginx/app_error.log;           
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://example.com:2110' always;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://example.com:2151' always;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";    
        }
    }
```

This is Compose file :

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dev-raurauapp:    
    #image: saad569/dev-raurau-app:${raurauapp_ssl_tag}
    image: saad569/dev-raurau-app:dev-raurauapp
    build:
      context: .    
      target: production
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - REACT_APP_DOMAIN_URL=https://example.com:2110
      - REACT_APP_IDENTITY_URL=https://example.com:2151
      - REACT_APP_LOGIN_URL=https://example.com/gateway        
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9000:3000      
    container_name: dev-raurauapp
 
  nginx:   
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes: 
      - ./site:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/example.com.crt:/etc/nginx/example.com.crt
      - ./nginx/example.com.key:/etc/nginx/example.com.key      
    depends_on:
      - dev-raurauapp
    container_name: dev-nginx
```

This is Docker file :

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS builder
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install --production
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
COPY . .
ENV GENERATE_SOURCEMAP false
RUN yarn build


FROM nginx:1.21.0-alpine as production
ENV NODE_ENV production
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is nginx.conf:

```
     server {
  listen 3000;
  
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```